# Encryption RC4 algorithm for integers

Tags: java, encryption, rc4-cipher

Basically I can successfully implement `RC4` algorithm for `String`s, which takes an  `Byte[]` array for the `key` :

```
byte [] key = "AAAAA".getBytes("ASCII");
```

If I take clearText as String say "24" then the cipher text range is very high, say > 2000 .
But for my algorithm, I need to restrict it to fewer range ~200.

So can I have better option for `int`'s ?

This is what I am doing with Strings :

**Encrypt Mode:**

```
  byte [] key = "AAAAA".getBytes("ASCII");

  String clearText = "66";


  Cipher rc4 = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
  SecretKeySpec rc4Key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "RC4");
  rc4.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rc4Key);
  byte [] cipherText = rc4.update(clearText.getBytes("ASCII"));
```

**Check values:**

```
      System.out.println("clear (ascii)        " + clearText);
      System.out.println("clear (hex)          " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(clearText.getBytes("ASCII")));
      System.out.println("cipher (hex) is      " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipherText));
```

**-** Can any trick be preformed on *these* types to get a lower *int* value?

**Decrypt** :

```
  Cipher rc4Decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
  rc4Decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rc4Key);
  byte [] clearText2 = rc4Decrypt.update(cipherText);
```

**SSCCE** :

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
public class MyArcFour
{

  public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {


      byte [] key = "AAAAA".getBytes("ASCII");

      String clearText = "66";


      Cipher rc4 = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
      SecretKeySpec rc4Key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "RC4");
      rc4.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rc4Key);

      byte [] cipherText = rc4.update(clearText.getBytes("ASCII"));

      System.out.println("clear (ascii)        " + clearText);
      System.out.println("clear (hex)          " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(clearText.getBytes("ASCII")));
      System.out.println("cipher (hex) is      " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipherText));


      Cipher rc4Decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
      rc4Decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rc4Key);
      byte [] clearText2 = rc4Decrypt.update(cipherText);

      System.out.println("decrypted (clear) is " + new String(clearText2, "ASCII"));
   }
}
```

Comment: "***then the cipher text range is very high, say > 2000***" What does this mean?

Comment: @Duncan the resultant string which I am getting after encryption, if you parse it to int, is high

Answer (score 3):

When using a *stream cipher* (as *RC4* is) the length of the ciphertext will always equal the length of the plaintext.

That means when you encrypt an `int` (which has 4 bytes), you will always receive another int (4 bytes) as encrypted output. So theoretically when you encrypt `0` you could get as a result `220`.
If you want a value in range `0 - 255` you can only encrypt a single byte.

Any good encryption algorithm must satisfy the property that when using the same encryption key `k` any distinct plaintext `p` must encrypt to a distinct ciphertext `c`.
This property is only achievable when `size(output) >= size(input)`.

**Why must that the be case?**
Well, consider the following encryption function:

```
/* output = E(key, input); key = 123 */

i | o
======
1 | 17
2 | 13
3 | 17
4 | 125
```

Then when you have the ciphertext `17` and the key `123` there is no way to tell if the originally encrypted value was `1` or `3`.

That means if you want to be able to **non ambiguously** decrypt the values afterwards, there is no way to decrease the size of the resulting ciphertext.

If decrypting is not necessary, you could always do `output % some_number` or use a *hash function* with desired output length.

Comment: It throws Exception that key must be > 40 bit :/

Comment: The length of the key must be `>= 40` bits (`5 bytes` or `String with 5 characters`). `key = 123` is just a hypotetical example for a hypotetical encryption function.